# getElementById is not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

#### My JS :

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            document.getElementById("xc").value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("yc").value = position.coords.longitude;                                                    
            document.getElementById("loginform").submit;
        });     
    } else {
        document.getElementById("xc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("yc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("loginform").submit;
    }
}
```

#### My HTML :

```
<form id="loginform" action="./functions/dologin.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="xc" name="xc" value="X">
    <input type="hidden" id="yc" name="yc" value="X">
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" onclick="getLocation();" value="Login">               
</form>
```

I've tried everything, from an `onsubmit="return getlocation();"` in the form - with button type submit, to jQuery to DOM

The value is always "X".

Comment: have you tried `element.setAttribute("value", "whateverhere");`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? It also looks like clicking on that button is instantly going to submit that form. Also, if you want to call `submit` on your form, you need to put some parentheses on there. `.submit()`

Comment: Does it work if you remove the action from the form? "Submit" buttons can trigger that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is getting submitted which is just causing the page to get reloaded which makes the changes you just made to the page get overwritten by the newly loaded page.

So, this is what it does:

1. Click button
2. Your Javascript code runs that modifies the page
3. Form gets submittted
4. Page gets reloaded - all your changes you just make to the page disappear

If you add a `return false;` to the end of your `getLocation()` and then return that in the HTML, it should stop the form from getting submitted.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            document.getElementById("xc").value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("yc").value = position.coords.longitude;                                                    
            document.getElementById("loginform").submit;
        });     
    } else {
        document.getElementById("xc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("yc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("loginform").submit;
    }
    // prevent default submit of the form
    return false;
}

<form id="loginform" action="./functions/dologin.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="xc" name="xc" value="X">
    <input type="hidden" id="yc" name="yc" value="X">
    <input class="myButton" type="submit" onclick="return getLocation();" value="Login">               
</form>
```

You could also change your button to just be a regular button, not a submit button and then there would be no default submit of the form.

```
<form id="loginform" action="./functions/dologin.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="xc" name="xc" value="X">
    <input type="hidden" id="yc" name="yc" value="X">
    <button class="myButton" onclick="getLocation();">Login</button>               
</form>
```

Comment: Returning false from `getLocation` won't do anything. Nothing is paying attention to its return value.

Comment: @Quentin - Added a return to their HTML onclick handler too.  Personally, I never put code in the HTML like that - bad practice in my opininion.  If you use `addEventListener()`, then the return is automatic.

Comment: @JamesBailey - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody! I made a couple of mistakes, and you all added! 
Code that works:

```
<script>
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                            document.getElementById("xc").value = position.coords.latitude;
                            document.getElementById("yc").value = position.coords.longitude;                                                    
                            document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
                        });     
    } else {
        document.getElementById("xc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("yc").value = '0';
        document.getElementById("loginform").submit();
    }
}
</script>



<form id="loginform" action="./functions/dologin.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="xc" name="xc" value="X">
    <input type="hidden" id="yc" name="yc" value="X">
    <input class="myButton" type="button" onclick="getLocation();" value="Login">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the function when the user clicks the submit button.

The function runs. Then the form submits.

The browser loads the new page before getting a response to the asynchronous location request.

You need to `return false` from your onclick function:

```
onclick="getLocation(); return false;"
```

Better yet, use [a modern way to bind events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and call `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

change the type of the input to `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16mgy0xm/11/

`<input class="myButton" type="button" onclick="getLocation();" value="Login">`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Chrome depreciated location in un-secure sites (like my development env)